# return a value in a table from a seperate table

Tags: excel, indexing, excel-formula, lookup

I have track and field results from 2 children. I've made separate sheets for each child.

The children did various events on various dates. 
I want to make an automated overview of the results in one table. 
That I can see in one row the results of the that event on various dates. 
I can do it manually, but it is time consuming. and chance for error.

I've attached the excel sheet [worksheet](https://1drv.ms/x/s!ArMXwOBUGPgTgS--reCDWep4b706)

I've looked to combine a `Vlookup` and `Hlookup` function as well as index,match,match function, but I only get a `#NA` return.

```
=VLOOKUP(A3;'Julian 2018'!A:C;HLOOKUP(B1;'Julian 2018'!A:C;2;FALSE);FALSE)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So in your case you could try this formula in `H2`:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($C$1:$C$75,MATCH(H$1&$G2,$A$1:$A$75&$B$1:$B$75,0)),"")
```

Or:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($C$1:$C$75,MATCH(1,(($A$1:$A$75=H$1)*($B$1:$B$75=$G2)),0)),"")
```

Enter both as array formula through <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>

Dutch variant:

```
=ALS.FOUT(INDEX($C$1:$C$75;VERGELIJKEN(H$1&$G2;$A$1:$A$75&$B$1:$B$75;0));"")
```

Or:

```
=ALS.FOUT(INDEX($C$1:$C$75;VERGELIJKEN(1;(($A$1:$A$75=H$1)*($B$1:$B$75=$G2));0));"")
```

Drag right and down....

[image]

Comment: eww, dutch Excel formula's :P (Belgian btw)

Comment: Thanks a lot. That did the trick. 
Dank je wel! (mijn excel staat wel op engels ;-) )